# In MySQL: How to pass a table name as stored procedure and/or function argument?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1146

For instance, this does not work:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE countRows(tbl_name VARCHAR(40))
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) as ct FROM tbl_name;
  END //

DELIMITER ;
CALL countRows('my_table_name');
```

Produces:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.tbl_name' doesn't exist
```

However, this works as expected:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as ct FROM my_table_name;
```

What syntax is required to use an argument as a table name in a select statement? Is this even possible?

Comment: Even if this were possible, this isn't a path you should go down.  Either build out the s'procs with the sql you really want, or just go ahead and embed the ad hoc sql in your code.

Comment: @Chris You can see the intent and the power here, right? Passing a table name to a generic function. I see it as perfectly legit and needed. Help me understand why it's bad to control a result set from a sproc? From what you're saying, if I have a .NET developer and a PHP developer I should ask them to both write their own code to get the same result set?

Comment: I see the intent, and it's flawed.  I highly suggest you read the following: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html  Although it covers ms sql server, the lessons are the same.

Comment: And here is another informative link: http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Little-Bobby-Tables-SQL-Injection-and-EXECUTE-AS.aspx

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) are what you need.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `test1`(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40) )
BEGIN
 SET @t1 =CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',tab_name );
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END $$
```

Comment: +1: You were first, & correct - you have to use Prepared Statements (MySQL's dynamic SQL): http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html

Comment: `CALL GetNumRows(gps_location)`
Returns:
`#1054 - Unknown column 'gps_location' in 'field list'`

Comment: @a1ex07 but if I want to declare a cursor, and I need to concat and call procedre in one statement?

Comment: @V_B: I think you need to ask a separate question, this one is quite old, and I don't see how having/not having cursors related to the original question...

Comment: @Pachonk gps_location would be something SQL can use at this point, a column name, variable...  The function concats a string, so that's what you must pass in.

Comment: Link to MySQL's prepared statement page is dead. This one works instead: [Prepared Statements in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 4):

**You can do it like this:**

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getDataUsingSiteCode`;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `getDataUsingSiteCode`(
          IN tab_name VARCHAR(40), 
          IN site_ VARCHAR(255)
       )
        BEGIN
          SET @site_code = site_;
          SET @sql_ =CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',tab_name,' WHERE site=?');
          PREPARE statement_ FROM @sql_;
          EXECUTE statement_ using @site_code;
        END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```