# How to pass table type parameter in store Procedure in MySQL like MS-SQL do?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

Can i pass table valued parameter in store procedure in MY-SQL like MS-SQL.

For sql procedure below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. usp_InsertProductionLocation  
    @TVP LocationTableType READONLY  
    AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2012.Production.Location  
           (Name  
           ,CostRate  
           ,Availability  
           ,ModifiedDate)  
        SELECT *, 0, GETDATE()  
        FROM  @TVP;  
        GO
```

For MySQL what should i do?

Comment: Does this helps? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977356/in-mysql-how-to-pass-a-table-name-as-stored-procedure-and-or-function-argument

Comment: NO, i want to pass multiple rows data(like table) sent from the front end and send to store procedure in my-sql. above link is to pass data from one table which is already store in table which is in database.

Comment: the PREPARE function is what you need like @PradipBorde suggested within his link.. But you need to be carefull because it can open you up to SQL injections.

Comment: MySQL doesn't provide a better way @annu . MySQL  doesn't provide a valued parameter within store procedures.. The only method is to go dynamic SQL building with the PREPARE function.

Comment: @annu You can store your data in temp table and then access it in stored proc.

Comment: @pradeip, but how can i pass table type value from front end to store procedure?

Comment: I don't think MySQL has the TABLE type for variables.
It's better if you have the stored procedure insert one line at a time, then use the front end to loop and call it multiple times.

Comment: @flip yes, i don't have any other option except loop :(

Comment: @annu It's not a bad thing. Your database is harder to scale than your front-end servers.